# Find set of objects in array that have same attributes

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

Given that I have an array with two attributes: `'n_parents'` and `'class'`, which looks like this:

```
my_arr = [{n_parents: 10, class: 'right'}, {n_parents: 10, class: 'right'}, {n_parents: 5, class: 'left'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}]
```

I would like to get an array with the objects that share most of those two attributes. So in the previous example:

```
result = [{n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}]
```

Because there are three objects that share `n_parents = 2`, and `class = 'center'`.

So far, I know how can I group by dos two attributes, but after that I am not sure how to get the set that has more elements.

Right now I have:

```
my_arr.group_by { |x| [x[:n_parents], x[:class]] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. It groups the hashes by the hash itself and then gets the largest group by the array count

```
 my_arr = [{n_parents: 10, class: 'right'}, {n_parents: 10, class: 'right'}, {n_parents: 5, class: 'left'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents: 2, class: 'center'}]
 my_arr.group_by { |h| h }.max_by { |h,v| v.count }.last
 #=>[{:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}, {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}, {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}]
```

Comment: You missed `#last` at end. So I was thinking, without the method, how you got the output.. ;)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I noticed and added it in why did you need to add spaces? clarity?

Comment: sure, as Ruby lover like that way to write. See [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)..

Comment: Okay I was just wondering since it obviously works either way. I am a huge ruby lover as well and my favorite part is that the syntax is almost white space ignorant. (Major reason I am not as big a fan of Python)

Answer (score 0):

something like below :

```
my_arr.group_by(&:values).max_by { |_,v| v.size }.last
# => [{:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"},
#     {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"},
#     {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using code used by OP and extending over that to get result he wants:--

```
my_arr.group_by { |x| [x[:n_parents], x[:class]] }.max_by{|k,v| v.size}.last
```

Output

```
#=> [{:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}, {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}, {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fourth answer to be posted.  The three earlier answers all employed `group_by`/`max_by`/`last`. Sure, that may be the best approach, but is it the most interesting, the most fun?  Here are a couple other ways to generate the desired result.  When

```
my_arr = [{n_parents: 10, class: 'right' }, {n_parents: 10, class: 'right' },
          {n_parents:  5, class: 'left'  }, {n_parents:  2, class: 'center'},
          {n_parents:  2, class: 'center'}, {n_parents:  2, class: 'center'}]
```

the desired result is:

```
  #=> [{:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"},
  #    {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"},
  #    {:n_parents=>2, :class=>"center"}]
```

**#1**

```
# Create a hash `g` whose keys are the elements of `my_arr` (hashes)
# and whose values are counts for the elements of `my_arr`.
# `max_by` the values (counts) and construct the array. 

el, nbr = my_arr.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h] = (g[h] ||= 0) + 1 }
                .max_by { |_,v| v } 
arr = [el]*nbr
```

**#2**

```
# Sequentially delete the elements equal to the first element of `arr`,
# each time calculating the number of elements deleted, by determining
# `arr.size` before and after the deletion. Compare that number with the
# largest number deleted so far to find the element with the maximum
# number of instances in `arr`, then construct the array. 

arr = my_arr.map(&:dup)
most_plentiful = { nbr_copies: 0, element: [] }
until arr.empty? do
  sz = arr.size
  element = arr.delete(arr.first)
  if sz - arr.size > most_plentiful[:nbr_copies]
    most_plentiful = { nbr_copies: sz - arr.size, element: element }
  end
end
arr = [most_plentiful[:element]]* most_plentiful[:nbr_copies]
```

Comment: Yes your code certainly works and is an interesting approach but at the same time down the road it would be refactored as it lacks the conciseness and readability of the other answers.

Comment: @engineersmnky,I agree 100%. If this were real-life, I would use group_by/max_by, like everyone else. I've learned a lot about Ruby, however, by trying to think up different, sometimes unconventional, solutions to SO questions, especially when I'm late to the party, as here. I post these musings in the hope they may have some educational value. Try it!